# Freestyle Line Flickers in Animation - How to Control?

Tags: python, rendering, freestyle

**The Problem:**

I'm attempting to adapt one of my vector-based characters to a 3d format for animation. This character, being a vector drawing usually, has big clean lines and cell shading.

Notice though that there is line flickering around the armpits and sometimes in the head region.

https://youtu.be/e2QG7gkwFtg

---

**Attempted solutions:**

I've attempted to solve this by using Face Smoothness settings, Chaining, and Min 2d (20), but no change on this.

---

**Other examples:**

I've looked at some other examples, which are mostly anime, and it seems that the drawings are complex enough where the issue I point out is not noticed (ie, many lines, nobody cares about flickering because its lost in the complexity) but with a character like this perfection is needed.

Any advice or is this an official limitation of Freestyle? I am not against custom scripting (I do python) if someone cares to tell me what angle I might approach this from.

Comment: To note, it can happen that the freestyle lines will render far off where it shouldn't be drawing, which is annoying.

Comment: I don't have my computer right now, but you could temporarily fix it by lengthening the freestyle line to draw further then it thinks it needs to draw.

Comment: I might be a step closer through using the simplification geometry modifier. Rendering a new animation now.

Comment: Seems like no one know how to fix the inaccuracies of freestyle.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and my solution was to turn every options in the Freestyle line set panel off except the first 3(silhouette, border contour). These settings have the least flicker problem and remain consistent through the shot.

Answer (score 1):

what generally helps is more render subdivision, but this will dramatically increase line rendering time of course...